# How to open an application in split screen through command line on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, split-window

I want to open a pdf on the left side of the screen and a word document on the other side of the screen through the command line or powershell on windows.

I also would like to be able to open one application on one screen and the other on the other screen.

(This is for my c# application.)

(Let me know if this is off-topic.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299371/c-sharp-move-a-window-to-secondary-screen